# Mpg123 builds for IOS and Android

Tags: android, c++, ios, build

I'm working with [Mpg123](https://www.mpg123.de/index.shtml) and using for implementation in my own cross-platform app. I'm working with C# and using PInvoke for calling native methods. There are no any problems to get dll for windows platform. The official site is providing ready builds for Windows. But there are no any builds for IOS and Android. I'm not familiar with building native C++ libraries for Android and IOS. And I'm interested in to know it.
Can you provide steps, what I have to do for this goals?